# How can I get Ubuntu version using Java

Tags: 14.04, java

I trying to get Ubuntu version using java, but there is a problem.

When using System.getProperty("os.version"), its return kernel version.
How can I get release version like "14.04" and etc

Comment: Parsing the output of `lsb_release -a` might work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the ProcessBuilder:

```
String[] args = new String[] {"/bin/bash", "-c", "lsb_release -r", "with", "args"};
Process proc = new ProcessBuilder(args).start();
```

Note: You need to use `lsb_release -r` to get only the version

Answer (score 2):

You can read it from the file `/etc/lsb-release`